# PHP file won't run from HTML button, but will run on it's own

Tags: php, html, bash

I am currently developing a website from HTML in order to control a relays on a USB Relay Board connected to a Raspberry Pi. I am running Apache and PHP.

The sequences is thus: I press a button on the website which runs a PHP file which then runs a Bash script, which then runs a command in the `/home/pi directory`. If I attempt to run the PHP file on its own, it will run without a problem and control one of the relays.

If I attempt to run a "hello world" php file (echo "hello world"), I see the hello world on the webpage. If I press the button, it redirects the page after running the php file like it should, but the relay doesn't respond. I've also restarted the RPi.

I've done this once before with a different system, but similar equipment, and it worked without an issue.

Comment: Why do you think the web server has the appropriate permissions to do what the script says?

Comment: I set the permissions on the file so that any user could execute it. I'm not exactly an expert at this

Comment: When you run the PHP manually, do you do it with the same user as the user running Apache?  Ex you run it with root, HTTP runs with the apache user?

Comment: No, but if i change the PHP file executed by the button on the HTML webpage, such as `echo "hello world"`, it will run without a problem, and I see `hello world` on my screen once I press the button, so I know that the apache user can run PHP files, and the script files that are run by the PHP files have been run under `chmod -Rv 777 *`, so everything in the directory has full access